# convert jupyter notebook to webpdf on mac

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, pip, nbconvert

I've encountered the problem of *nbconvert failed: Playwright is not installed to support Web PDF conversion. Please install `nbconvert[webpdf]` to enable.*, when I was planning to convert jupyter notebook into webpdf on my mac, after that I've download the pyppeteer and nbconvert by using `pip install command`, I still couldn't convert jupyter notebook file into webpdf, why's that? Do I need to `brew install that` or something? (besides, I can already convert notebook to pdf by installing Tex related packages on my computer)

1. search the web, and stackover flow in particular, and type in the command `pip install nbconvert` and `pip instal pyppeteer`
2. tried the converting process (notebook to webpdf) again in my chrome (with jupyter notebook on of course)
3. I just wanna see the difference between webpdf and pdf (which I've already succeeded converting)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry guys, I should've tried out more...

After I type in the command line:
`jupyter nbconvert C3_W2_Collaborative_RecSys_Assignment.ipynb --to webpdf --debug --allow-chromium-download`, I found that there's one python package missing: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playwright'`, then I installed that by typing `pip install playwright` and type in the converting command again, pop!, problem solved.